# Output 2 different queries to a single resultset

Tags: sql

My db schema is something like this -

```
Table - 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Src_Country_Code|Total_Src_Amount|Dest_Country_Code|Total_Dest_Amount|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the output in the following form -

```
Country_Code||SrcAmount||Dest_Amount
```

Country_Code is present in both Src_Country_Code and Dest_Country_Code : eg-

Sample records

```
abc|50|efg|100       
efg|400|abc|200
```

The output If I select the country abc should be like-

```
abc|50|200
```

Also, if the second record doesn't exist, the output should be -

```
abc|50|0
```

I tried a lot of variations but nothing seems to work. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
SELECT nvl(src.Src_Country_Code, dest.Dest_Country_Code) Country_Code,
       nvl(Total_Src_Amount,0) Total_Src_Amount,
       nvl(Total_Dest_Amount, 0) Total_Dest_Amount
FROM
  (SELECT Src_Country_Code,
          sum(Total_Src_Amount) Total_Src_Amount
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY Src_Country_Code) src
FULL JOIN src.Src_Country_Code = dest.dest_Country_Code
  (SELECT Dest_Country_Code,sum(Total_dest_Amount) Total_dest_Amount
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY Dest_Country_Code) dest
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was nearly correct. Apologies for the delayed reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Join like below.

```
SELECT T1.Src_Country_Code,T1.Total_Src_Amount,T2.Total_Dest_Amount 
FROM Table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table1 T2 ON T1.Src_Country_Code = T2.Dest_Country_Code
```

Working Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34723/1